# How to use RealSense's spatial_filter on an OpenCV Mat?

Tags: opencv, filtering, noise-reduction, realsense

I want to apply RealSense library's depth filtering (`rs2::spatial_filter`) on an OpenCV `Mat`, but it seems like the filter is not being applied. The original depth image and the supposedly filtered depth image look exactly the same.

To load raw depth data into `rs2::frame`, I used modified [@Groch88's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57394410/15587063). One of the changes I made was changing the depth format from `RS2_FORMAT_Z16` to `RS2_FORMAT_DISTANCE` (to be able to load a `float` depth map) and not loading the RGB part of the frame. The whole source is below.

Why do the original and the filtered images look exactly the same? Am I missing something obvious?

main.cpp:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <librealsense2/rs.hpp>
#include "rsImageConverter.h"

int main()
{
    cv::Mat rawDepthImg = load_raw_depth("/path/to/depth/image"); // loads float depth image
    rsImageConverter ic{rawDepthImg.cols, rawDepthImg.rows, sizeof(float)};

    if ( !ic.convertFrame(rawDepthImg.data, rawDepthImg.data) )
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not load depth.\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    rs2::frame rsDepthFrame = ic.getDepth();

    // Filter
    // https://dev.intelrealsense.com/docs/post-processing-filters
    rs2::spatial_filter spat_filter;
    spat_filter.set_option(RS2_OPTION_FILTER_MAGNITUDE, 2.0f);
    spat_filter.set_option(RS2_OPTION_FILTER_SMOOTH_ALPHA, 0.5f);
    spat_filter.set_option(RS2_OPTION_FILTER_SMOOTH_DELTA, 20.0f);

    // Apply filtering
    rs2::frame rsFilteredDepthFrame;
    rsFilteredDepthFrame = spat_filter.process(rsDepthFrame);

    // Copy filtered depth to OpenCV Mat
    cv::Mat filteredDepth = cv::Mat::zeros(rawDepthImg.size(), CV_32F);
    memcpy(filteredDepth.data, rsFilteredDepthFrame.get_data(), rawDepthImg.cols * rawDepthImg.rows * sizeof(float));

    // Display (un)filtered images
    cv::imshow("Original depth", rawDepthImg); // Original image is being shown
    cv::imshow("Filtered depth", filteredDepth); // A depth image that looks exactly like the original unfiltered depth map is shown
    cv::imshow("Diff", filteredDepth - rawDepthImg); // A black image is being shown
    cv::waitKey(0);

    return 0;
}
```

rsImageConverter.h (edited version of [@Doch88's code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57394410/15587063)):

```cpp
#include <librealsense2/rs.hpp>
#include <librealsense2/hpp/rs_internal.hpp>

class rsImageConverter
{
public:
    rsImageConverter(int w, int h, int bppDepth);

    bool convertFrame(uint8_t* depth_data, uint8_t*  color_data);

    rs2::frame getDepth() const;

private:
    int w = 640;
    int h = 480;
    int bppDepth = sizeof(float);

    rs2::software_device dev;
    rs2::software_sensor depth_sensor;
    rs2::stream_profile depth_stream;
    rs2::syncer syncer;

    rs2::frame depth;

    int ind = 0;
};
```

rsImageConverter.cpp (edited version of [@Doch88's code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57394410/15587063)):

```cpp
#include "rsImageConverter.h"

rsImageConverter::rsImageConverter(int w, int h, int bppDepth) :
        w(w),
        h(h),
        bppDepth(bppDepth),
        depth_sensor(dev.add_sensor("Depth")) // initializing depth sensor
{

    rs2_intrinsics depth_intrinsics{ w, h, (float)(w / 2), (float)(h / 2), (float) w , (float) h , RS2_DISTORTION_BROWN_CONRADY ,{ 0,0,0,0,0 } };
    depth_stream = depth_sensor.add_video_stream({  RS2_STREAM_DEPTH, 0, 0,
                                                    w, h, 60, bppDepth,
                                                    RS2_FORMAT_DISTANCE, depth_intrinsics });
    depth_sensor.add_read_only_option(RS2_OPTION_DEPTH_UNITS, 1.f); // setting depth units option to the virtual sensor

    depth_sensor.open(depth_stream);
    depth_sensor.start(syncer);
}

bool rsImageConverter::convertFrame(uint8_t*  depth_data, uint8_t*  color_data)
{
    depth_sensor.on_video_frame({ depth_data, // Frame pixels
                                  [](void*) {}, // Custom deleter (if required)
                                  w*bppDepth, bppDepth, // Stride and Bytes-per-pixel
                                  (rs2_time_t)ind * 16, RS2_TIMESTAMP_DOMAIN_HARDWARE_CLOCK, ind, // Timestamp, Frame# for potential sync services
                                  depth_stream });

    ind++;

    rs2::frameset fset = syncer.wait_for_frames();
    depth = fset.first_or_default(RS2_STREAM_DEPTH);

    return depth;
}

rs2::frame rsImageConverter::getDepth() const
{
    return depth;
}
```